# What made Bronach and Ben sad?

Tags: plot-explanation, song-of-the-sea

In *Song of the Sea*, why did Bronach look sorrowful when Ben asked her not to take Saoirse away, and why did Ben cry after seeing this reaction of Bronach?

I think I got the metaphorical structure of the film, but I cannot understand this scene.